# How to download reports from paperboy?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, airflow

I have installed paperboy using steps given at https://github.com/timkpaine/paperboy.git

Python Version: 3.7

Paperboy: master branch

and executed using

```
python -m paperboy
```

Uploaded a sample.ipynb file and generated reports.
[image]

But could not able to download reports.
Please suggest a way to download reports shown in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't implemented yet.
Check: https://github.com/timkpaine/paperboy/issues/94